# What is the difference between RFC1123 and RFC2822 DateTime formatting in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, rfc2822, rfc1123

This is out of curiosity rather than because I need to know it at this point, but in the PHP manual, they're identical; I can't see the reason that there are two different data formats for the same thing.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
const string RFC1123 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**[RFC1123](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)** is "Requirements for Internet Hosts - Application and Support", October 1989

**[RFC2822](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)** is "Internet Message Format", April 2001

Think of **RFC1123** as a parent to **RFC2822**. It references **RFC2822** as the appropriate spec for date/time, which are as follows:

> 3.3. Date and Time Specification
>
> Date and time occur in several header fields.  This section
>   specifies    the syntax for a full date and time specification. 
>   Though folding    white space is permitted throughout the date-time
>   specification, it    is RECOMMENDED that a single space be used in
>   each place that FWS    appears (whether it is required or optional);
>   some older    implementations may not interpret other occurrences of
>   folding white    space correctly.
>
> date-time       =       [ day-of-week "," ] date FWS time [CFWS]
>
> day-of-week     =       ([FWS] day-name) / obs-day-of-week
>
> day-name        =       "Mon" / "Tue" / "Wed" / "Thu" /
>                           "Fri" / "Sat" / "Sun"
>
> date            =       day month year
>
> year            =       4*DIGIT / obs-year
>
> month           =       (FWS month-name FWS) / obs-month
>
> month-name      =       "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" /
>                           "May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug" /
>                           "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"
>
> day             =       ([FWS] 1*2DIGIT) / obs-day
>
> time            =       time-of-day FWS zone
>
> time-of-day     =       hour ":" minute [ ":" second ]
>
> hour            =       2DIGIT / obs-hour
>
> minute          =       2DIGIT / obs-minute
>
> second          =       2DIGIT / obs-second
>
> zone            =       (( "+" / "-" ) 4DIGIT) / obs-zone

Comment: Also worth noting: RFC1123 references RFC822. RFC2822 obsoletes RFC822.

Comment: Thanks both, curiosity satisfied!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is documentation. The date formats may be the same, but they are defined in different documents independently. And let's be honest

```
const string COMMON_DATE_FORMAT_FOR_RFC1123_AND_2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
```

would not be quite as usable.